# Ignoring BGRT: invalid Ubuntu 14.04.03

Tags: 14.04, boot

I booted my computer and it took me to GRUB which was unexpected because I am only running Ubuntu and nothing else. The choices are: Ubuntu, Advanced option for Ubuntu, System setup. I select ubuntu. I put in my passphrase. My computer screen then displays:

```
[ 0.045025] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[ 1.345025] ACPI PCC probe failded.

BusyBox v1.21.1 (ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubunu1) build-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.03 on a Toshiba Satellite L:55-A5284. I don't know what kernel I am using.

Answer (score -1):

It is very much possible(and normal) to have GRUB(and various options for GRUB) even if you are using only Ubuntu. Those options gives you some flexibility to try out various options in the only O/S(Ubuntu) that you have.